# Как сделать чтобы программа на Python открывалась сразу после включения Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

Я делаю **голосового помощника** на **Python** и мне нужно чтобы программа включалась вместе с **Windiws 10**, то есть когда включается **компьютер**, включается и **программа**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделай из .py exe, например с помощью Pyinstaller и положи в папку автозагрузки. Путь кажется такой: C:\Users\имя-пользователя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup